# How to calibrate current transformer such as SCT-013 without having to actually generate the actual current?

Tags: transformer

I have a current transformer like this [one](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1BBN.KruWBuNjSszgq6z8jVXaE.jpg) but is rated at lower Ampere rating (30A/1V). I would like verify how accurate its reading is. I will be using it read the current consumption on a 220V mains line

Is there some way to verify its reading without actually having to generate the Ampere on a line. I do not own an AC bench supply that can generate that amount of power. Even the lowest rating that I can buy for this transformer is 10A that is still a lot of power to generate.

I hope that going further after changing the burden resistor built in, I will be able to confirm the reading is accurate to at least 1%. All equipment I have access to is a DC bench power supply, multimeter, digital oscilloscope, and a function generator. Is there some way to validate its reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *All equipment i have access to is a DC bench power supply, Digital
>   Oscilloscope, and a function generator.*

Use your signal generator set at 50 Hz or 60 Hz and, through the primary hole wind ten turns (or more) but note the number. Drive current through those ten turns and monitor that current using your multimeter. If you can get 100 mA RMS through 20 turns, that's equivalent to 2 A RMS in a single primary wire. If that isn't enough, wind more primary turns (say 100) or, build a little DC power amplifier to produce more current into the home-spun winding.

Comment: the diameter and the type of wire does not matter right?

Comment: I like how simple and easily done you solution is good sir, but how accurate will this method be? Assuming of course that i have done everything perfectly

Comment: It all comes down to how accurately you can measure the current produced by the multimeter. If you don't have an accurate current measurement you could use a small resistor and measure the voltage across that resistor but then it comes down to how accurate is your voltage measurement equipment and what resistor tolerance you have.

Comment: I do have some 0.1% resistors, and my multimeter are rated at 1% on both voltage and current. I Have some additional questions on the setup if you dont mind, When you say "If you can get 100 mA RMS through 20 turns" i am reading from the SCT transformer or is this a reading i should get on  the home spun wire?

Comment: This is the current through the home-spun wire.

Comment: I dont think the signal generator that i have has enough power to drive, i do not mind building a simple circuit since i will be testing several. I searched for a driver circuit and [this circuit](https://openemt.org/index.php?title=AC_current_amplifier) showed up. what do you think?

Comment: It might be easier to wind more turns than build a circuit. The circuits in that link were a little low on information. You can use something like a BJT (or darlington) buffer amp as per this site: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-buffer-an-op-amp-output-for-higher-current-part-2/

Comment: alright what would be the formula from what you have said  RMS current (A) x No. of Turns = Single line current. Am not sure if the function generator has a feature that tells how much current it outputs, so if i ever use a resistor would the formula be  RMS current = (Vp-p/sqrt(2)) / Resistor Value ?

Comment: If 100 mA feeds through ten turns, it creates the same magnetic field as 1 amp flowing through 1 turn. Ditto 10 mA through 100 turns.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of is to place it over a wire going to your electric heater or an electric stove and verify the current with an AC ammeter. If you have only one multimeter, check the current with it first, and then measure the AC voltage from this transformer.

Since you don't mention a multimeter, you could use a very small value resistor on the neutral side (like 0.1Ω), measure the AC voltage across it, leave it in the circuit and measure the AC voltage from the current transformer. Your AC voltage measurement would be done with the oscilloscope. Just remember that the AC voltage RMS value is 0.707 times the peak voltage.

Comment: Hello I do have a AC multimeter, but its a very cheap AC clamp multimeter its accuracy is sketchy

Comment: I don't like the suggestion of measuring the voltage on a shunt in the neutral using an oscilloscope without giving a clear warning of the dangers of this - particularly if there is any chance that the scope GND is connected to mains earth. The other problem is that now you have to calibrate the 0.1 Ω resistor.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources in the average home ie heater, stove, water heater, many lights turned on...  your real problem seems to be that you need an excellent quality ampmeter which reads much better than 1% to be used as a reference.  Might I suggest you settle on the accuracy of a meter your budget will allow.  Please keep in mind frequency and load impedance will affect linearity of the readings.  Modifying the resistor will only change calibration of output for one value, the other readings may become worse.